# Exercise about map object ("Conceptual Mathematics Second Edition", p.315, Article V Map objects, Exercise 6)

Tags: category-theory

I feel difficult to show the existence of a map $\gamma$ which corresponds to the composition of two maps.

$\gamma$ is the following map.

$$\gamma: B^A \times C^B \to C^A$$

And I want to show that for any two maps $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$, there exists a map $\gamma$ satisfying the following equation

$$\gamma(\widetilde{f}, \widetilde{g}) = \widetilde{g \circ f}$$

where I think $\widetilde{f}$, $\widetilde{g}$, and $\widetilde{g \circ f}$ are the maps from terminal object

$$\widetilde{f}: 1 \to B^A$$
$$\widetilde{g}: 1 \to C^B$$
$$\widetilde{g \circ f}: 1 \to C^A.$$

I tried to show the existence of $\gamma$ using the existence of evaluation maps $e1$, $e2$, and $e3$ satisfying the following commutative diagrams, but can't proceed the next step.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason a map "from" the terminal object would be unique/well-defined?

Comment: In cartesian closed category, there is a terminal object.   But a map from the  terminal object don't necessarily exists?

Comment: By adjunction, you need to produce a map $A\times B^A\times C^B\to C$. Using your maps $e_1$ and $e_2$, can you do it ?

Comment: It is $e2 \circ e1 \times 1_{C^B }$ ?

Comment: Yes. If you think about it, in the category of sets, this is exactly $(x,f,g)\mapsto (f(x),g)\mapsto g(f(x))$. Hence, it adjoint is $(f,g)\mapsto (x\mapsto g(f(x))=g\circ f$.